# How to migrate C# project from VS2008 to VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2017, port

I have a `C#` project built in `Visual Studio 2008` and I am not able to open this project in `Visual Studio 2017`.

**So how to migrate the existing C# project from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2017?**

Comment: Use VS2015 first. It can open the VS2008 project. Then you upgrade the project to VS2015 format before you re-open it with VS2017. Note: install the VS2013 in a VM because these damn things don't play nice with each other. I've got different VMs to load VS2013, VS2015 and VS2017 projects because VS is that retarded.

Comment: What kind of project? In theory, it should be auto-upgraded when you open the solution. What error shows up exactly? We can't really help when the information you provided is so little.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a new vs 2017 project and import the existing code files from the vs 2008 project into the new one. If it's a single project, it shouldn't be that much work...